# Is it safe to run Elastic APM on production servers?

Tags: elastic-apm

Elastic APM uses a Java agent to collect application performance metrics and sends it to the Elastic APM server, which means it will use Java instrumentation for underlying metrics in JVM.

My question is:

Is there any vulnerability issue or security risk for using it?

Answer (score -1):

currently,we run apm-agent for java application, but after 1 day, server cpu has over 100% and java application killed by system

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explanation and clarification about the systems that you were running, and the reasons why the system failed. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer